# Update .net Core App docker image for latest security patches

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

We have 10+ microservices developed in .net core 3.1 (Currently using 3.1.12 runtime). These microservices are packaged as docker image and deployed to AWS ECS.
There is a need to periodically update these microservices to use the latest .net core 3.1 runtime mainly for security patches as they get released.

It takes a lot of churn to update all the microservices to update to the latest patches because these security patches typically get released in a month cadence.

What is the best practice for updating the .net Core apps docker image for latest patches?

Comment: What container orchestration tools are you using?

Comment: Using AWS ECS for container orchestration.